# SQL User Permissions for Continuous Integration via DbUp and Octopus

Tags: sql-server, permissions, deployment, integration

Currently, our deverloper group has started using DbUp and Octopus to do Continuous Integration on SQL Database Deployments. We have created a Domain user which will utilized to do the SQL Database deployment via Octopus server.

I wanted to know, what permissions should a Domain user should be granted for Continuous Integration process?

I don't want to give "SysAdmin" permission to this Domain user.

Do people have implemented above combination for there Continuous Integration of DB Deployment?

Comment: Added `sql-server` tag based on the mentioning of `sqlcmd`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using SQL Server 2008 and up, A better way of doing is to create a role in the database and grant that role permissions.

You can add users to the role, so they will inherit the permissions of the role.

-- to grant CREATE, ALTER, DROP OBJECTS (tables, procs, functions, views) with ALTER permissions on the schema. You can obviously fine tune below ones as per your needs.

```
USE db_name;
 CREATE ROLE [new_role] AUTHORIZATION [dbo];
grant alter
      ,delete
      ,execute
      ,insert
      ,references
      ,select
      ,update
      ,view definition
on schema::dbo
to new_role;

grant create table
     ,create procedure
     ,create function
     ,create view
to new_role;
```

-- Add an existing user to the new role created

```
  EXEC sp_addrolemember 'new_role', 'DBUserName'
  GO
```

Comment: Thank you Colin 't Hart for adding comment and Thank you Kin for your response.
Yes, we are using SQL 2008, 2008 R2, 2012 in our environment

Comment: I unchecked the answer, as I wanted to get more information on, what are the other approach people are using to setup a user, which can be utilized under Continuous Integration for the database deployment.

Comment: @NismoGTR05 I completely agree with you, but I believe that is what the upvotes are for - if an answer is helpful, upvote it. Its not necessary that an accepted answer will be the best answer. There are cases where other answers are having more upvotes than the accepted answer. I am curious what other approaches are you looking for ?

Comment: I am curious to know, if anybody implemented auto DB deployment and try to avoid failure security wise during the deployment